# How to use a DEPLOY_TOKEN to install an R package from a Gitlab private repository?

Tags: r, gitlab-ci

First, a working command:

using GITLAB_PAT variable, set in .Renviron file

```
cred <- git2r::cred_token( token = 'GITLAB_PAT' );

remotes::install_gitlab('myuser/myproject',
                        credentials = cred ,upgrade = FALSE )
```

install works! but gives access to all private packages of myuser.

Using GitLab PAT from envvar GITLAB_PAT

```
Downloading GitLab repo myuser/myproject@master

from URL https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/12345678/repository/archive.tar.gz?sha=master

√  checking for file 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpCMKBuc\remotes7e0820dc515b\myproject-master-b31c5baa8f1d2d4967b00b739216cbb9b50d74b1/DESCRIPTION' (2.8s)
-  preparing 'myproject': (526ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  building 'myproject_0.1.0.tar.gz'
...

** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path

* DONE (myproject)
```

Second, my non working try to use DEPLOY_TOKEN:

using a DEPLOY_TOKEN , set in .Renviron file, to have read access to only the repo containing the package

```
cred <- git2r::cred_token( token = 'MYPROJECT_TOKEN' );

remotes::install_gitlab('myuser/myproject',
                        credentials = cred ,upgrade = FALSE )
```

-> message saying that access is granted using Gitlab PAT, which in not what I want.

Using GitLab PAT from envvar GITLAB_PAT

```
Skipping install of 'myproject' from a gitlab remote, the SHA1 (b31c5bac) has not changed since last install.

Use `force = TRUE` to force installation
```

In summary, can I use DEPLOY_TOKEN to install an R package from a private project on Gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

I found usefull video on group deploy token https://www.youtube.com/embed/8kxTJvaD9ks?rel=0

that gave int:

```
git clone https://gitlab+deploy-token-157011:-vz-oxsbL2y_ffdZoedq@gitlab.com/myuser/myproject.git
```

With this direction, this works:
(extract from .gitlab-ci.yml)

```
`- R -e "devtools::install_git(paste0('https://',Sys.getenv('DEPLOY_USERNAME'),":", 
                         Sys.getenv('DEPLOY_TOKEN'),
                         '@gitlab.com/myuser/myproject.git"'), upgrade = FALSE)"`
```

with gitlab variables

DEPLOY_USERNAME=gitlab+deploy-token-157011
and
DEPLOY_TOKEN=-vz-oxsbL2y_ffdZoedq